# how to store server $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] as id in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to store the Ip address as an Id in the database. 
For that, i first use `str-replace` to strip of the dots.

```
$ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$user_id = str_replace(".","",$ipAddress);
```

My query looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
`id` int(24) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`text` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Problem: he stores the `user_id` as "2147483647" in the database

For testing i did an echo of the `$user_id;` and it gives me this value (my ip): `9421491192`

So why it is storing another value in the DB and not my ip like above?

Comment: Don't do this..

Comment: IDs should be auto incremented, as you did in your DDL. Don't use anything else as an ID because this will give you only problems in the future.

Comment: It's best to create a `ip_address` column and store this there.

Comment: Removing the dots is horrible. `1.23.45.67` will produce the same value as `12.34.5.67`

Comment: ok. But i still do not understand why he changes the value; because `9421491192` is a normal integer

Comment: If you want to convert an IP address to a number, use `ip2long()`.

Comment: Make a new field for ip storage, unsigned int(11), and then ip2long() in php, or INET_ATON in mysql. To reverse it, long2ip() in php, or INET_NTOA in mysql.

Comment: `2147483647` is the largest value a signed `int` column can store. Everything about what you're doing is wrong/bad - IPs aren't ints, they're not user IDs, removing the dots is horrible. Start over.

Comment: `ip2long()` works fine!

Answer (score 0):

1. Your id column should just be an auto_incremented number column. As in, do not use the IP here.
2. If you are going to strip the dots, pad the octets so that the end up remaining 3 digits, that way 1.23.45.67 and 12.34.5.67 do not end up being the same thing. However, I would suggest completely skipping this step and just keeping the dots.
3. Make a separate column for the IP addresses and store it as a char or string field.
4. Make a unique index on the ip_address column.